# Any way to get VS to recognise ReSharper razor errors and fail compilation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, resharper

Is there any way to do this? The razor support in ReSharper 6 is excellent, and it would be nice for the compiler to recognise razor view errors as compile time errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no way treat ReSharper errors as compile errors.
But you can enable Solution Wide Analysis and will be informed if there are any errors in solution from ReSharper.
Also, you can enable own Microsoft analysis of views during build time - look at this article http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx